# WEVTUtil export certain event

Tags: windows, batch-file, event-viewer, wevtutil

I want to export only event id 4624 from Security

Code below exports all event from security (i want only 4624);

```
WEVTUtil query-events Security /rd:true /format:text > %~dp0Logins.txt /q:"<EventID>4624</EventID>"
```

When all 4624 events exported i want filter only events with:

```
<Data Name='LogonProcessName'>User32 </Data>
```

This will be RDP logs with IP, because logs in "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational" dont have IP (only username) :( I heard this is because RDP connection is TLS secured...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I want to export only `Event ID 4624` from Security

> ```
> WEVTUtil query-events Security /rd:true /format:text > "%~dp0Logins.txt"<EventID>4624</EventID>"
> ```

You are using the wrong format for the `/q` option.

Use the following command line:

```
wevtutil qe Security "/q:*[System [(EventID=4648)]]" /rd:true /f:text > "%~dp0Logins.txt"
```

---

#### How do I restrict the filter to `Event ID 4624` containing `User32`?

> When all 4624 events exported I want filter only events with:
>
> ```
> <Data Name='LogonProcessName'>User32 </Data>
> ```

Use the following command line:

```
wevtutil qe Security "/q:*[System [(EventID=4648)]]" /rd:true | findstr User32 >nul && wevtutil qe Security "/q:*[System [(EventID=4648)]]" /f:text /rd:true > "%~dp0Logins.txt"
```

Code based on the following source link.

Source [How to use wevtutil command to get event details if it only comply with specific text or word](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bb2208b2-e2b7-4e80-a6da-79aa1444957d/how-to-use-wevtutil-command-to-get-event-details-if-it-only-comply-with-specific-text-or-word?forum=winserverManagement)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [wevutil](http://ss64.com/nt/wevtutil.html) - Windows Events Command Line Utility.

Comment: Thanks, filter works well! Can you please fix %~dp0Logins.txt issue for folders with spaces in names?

Comment: It seems only first example works, but filtering isnt :/

Comment: @acidmagic What is the exact command line you are running? Is there an error? Does it work if you just output to a file called `Logins.txt`?

Comment: `wevtutil qe Security "/q:*[System [(EventID=4624)]]" /rd:true /c:1| findstr User32 >nul && wevtutil qe Security "/q:*[System [(EventID=4624)]]" /f:text /rd:true /c:1 > "%~dp0logs.txt"`

And am not getting any output (logs.txt) User32 exists in event 4624

Comment: Please try removing both occurrences of `/c:1` Answer updated

Comment: same thing :( i get logs.txt output with all events 4624 (with or without user32 string)